# Windows Phone 8 facebook login (Beta)

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-8

I've been going through the instructions here trying to implement the FB login via the FB Beta application: http://facebooksdk.net/docs/phone/sso/

I had it working for a while, however ever since the last Beta update, something started failing.

Whenever i get a callback to MapUri from the FB application, i don't get the proper Uri being passed in. The following code always fails (the uri contains mundane URIs of pages within the application, not what i expected).

```
AppAuthenticationHelper.IsFacebookLoginResponse(uri)
```

I might have changes something on the web-configuration of the application, or on the WP8, however going over the settings, nothing seems to be working.

I checked the usual suspects (AppIds, ProductIds etc...) and it seems to be running properly, so that changing one of those IDs throws the error like i expect it to, however when i have setup everything properly, i get the facebook application to open my application, however the UriMapperBase when it get's called never has the proper Uri in it.

Here is the configuration for the WMAppManifest for the extension:

```
<Extensions>
<Protocol Name="msft-54045783c54e4c3a9f2b470c5b7ba353" NavUriFragment="encodedLaunchUri=%s" TaskID="_default" />
</Extensions>
```

Any ideas?

P.S. I am testing this  on real devices with the latest FB Beta application.

UPDATE: Seems to only affect Samsung phones, no issues with HTC, haven't tried other ones.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18782579/wp8-facebook-login-issue

Comment: This is not using the web-browser to login, it is doing an IPC call to open the FB application, so their problem is a bit different.